# Can I use Battle.Net balance to purchase items from the US/North America RMAH if I'm in the UK?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

When I installed Diablo 3 from the us.battle.net website, I didn't know it would default my region to the US. This means that I cannot use the RMAH in North America (where my level 60 Monk is that I want to continue playing) to pay for items in real-world currency. You can only do so within the region that you reside (i.e. EU for myself).

My question: am I able to purchase items on the North America/US RMAH using Battle.net balance if I'm in the UK?

As far as I can see, the [FAQ](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-balance-faq) doesn't answer this.

***EDIT***

The attached question marking this one as a duplicate doesn't answer it directly, and its title isn't helpful hence why I didn't find it previously.

Regardless, once enabling battle.net balance by adding an authenticator to my account, I cannot use the US-region RMAH in-game.

Comment: what do you mean by battle net points?

Comment: Battle.net Balance! Sorry, I'll amend the post.

Comment: I don't believe you can, however I have never tried. I think the balances across regions are kept separate from each other though

Comment: I have skimmed & searched the Terms of Use and other legal docs and it is still unclear. Guess I'll just have to try!

Comment: well if you don't get an answer from somebody who knows here, I would recommend contacting Blizzard support before giving them money to put on the Battle.net balance

Comment: The FAQ does answer the question indirectly: Q4 - What currencies can I use to increase my Battle.net Balance?: Battle.net Balances for different currencies are tracked separately and cannot be used interchangeably.  It's still best to ask Blizzard as these policies change over time.

Comment: I had my Battle.net account hacked at one point and everything was changed to point to the UK. When I contacted Blizzard about this they told me they needed to change my region to the US for everything to work the way it should.